# RHEL Desktop: How to install g++?

Tags: gcc, rhel-6

I would like to install the `gcc-c++` package on RHEL 6. When I search for it with yum, I get `No matches found`.

Searching for it on the web, it seems that I need the `workstation` sub-channel. However, I have no idea how to get it. Do I need to buy a workstation subscription for that? It is not listed in `yum repolist all`.

I used the Subscription Manager to activate the license, most documentation only applies when using RHN classic, so I'm a bit lost right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the repository has nothing to do with the workstation sub-channel, it's called `rhel-6-desktop-optional-rpms`. After I enabled that in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo`, yum found the `gcc-c++` package.

Comment: You may also enable it using the command `sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-6-desktop-optional-rpms`.

Answer (score 0):

How about installing it from your DVD?

For my RHEL 6.4, the RPM file can be found under the folder `X:\Packages`.